# Is it safe to commit to the hiring process of an academic research position without an official offer letter?

Tags: postdocs, job-search, job, germany

After being offered a postdoctoral position by email, I was asked by the university’s administration to submit some documents allowing them to start the hiring process. According to them, this process will take 2 months.

I was wondering if it is wise/safe to wait this long without an official letter at hand. If not, how should I proceed?

Note that I am aware of the position details based on the job description and the discussion with the PI, but I was expecting some official document (signed by the administration/PI).

I have seen [this similar question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/140999/how-to-deal-with-the-postdoc-offer-without-a-contract), but I have added a country tag to my question so that I can get specific answers.

Thanks in advance for sharing your thoughts on this!

Comment: Keep looking.  If you find a firm offer that's about as good, take it!

Comment: Where are you based right now? Which citizenship do you have?

Comment: @user151413 non-EU citizenship, but currently-based in another EU country. (Sorry, I prefer not to mention explicitly which ones for anonymity) Why do you think this matters? Is it for the in-person signature of the contract as you mention below? (Thanks btw, it seems I don't have enough reputation to upvote)

Comment: @mbl20 Primarily because if you are a non-EU citizen, you might need a visa (even if you have a Schengen visa right now - but this is tied to a different job), and (as mentioned below) visa processes take time.  On the other hand, for a visa application you *do* need a letter from the university stating that they will hire you.  If that's the situation, it might make sense to check what part of the process takes 2 months.  (Also note that hirings typically go through the staff council, which can take its time, especially at large universitites/research institutes.)

Comment: @user151413 Thanks for clarifying! I've been told that the 2 months are for preparing the work contract, without explicitly mentioning what the different steps involved would be. It might include, as you say, the staff council. The visa is a whole different story, not accounted for in that duration (unless I start it in parallel...)

Comment: @mbl20 The thing is: If it is a publicly funded position, it has to be first "publicly advertised" for e.g. 2 weeks, before the process can even start.

Comment: @user151413 not sure how the funding is managed exactly. But, the position was advertised, this is how I knew about it :)

Comment: @mbl20 Yes, but the question is whether this was the "official" i.e. formal advertisement.  It is not uncommon to solicit applications, then select a candidate, and then only do the formal official advertisement (which is then rather focused).

Comment: @user151413 ok, I wasn't aware of this, thanks! Is there a way to know whether it's publicly-funded (besides explicitly asking the PI)? Are there some keywords to look for in the description perhaps?

Comment: @mbl20 Certainly not in the informal ad. You can try to figure out if the PI has grants from private agencies. But it could well be that the rules are that *all* jobs have to be officially advertised.

Comment: This is very common in Germany: public service contracts can take one to two months to prepare. They also won't sign anything until they have checked that all your documents are ok, but at that point, they will directly send you the contract. This is somewhat unfortunate for the PIs, who cannot guarantee anything beforehand, but it does not seem that it is a priority for them to speed up the process...

Comment: Don't you think "this will take two months" could be true only if it included time for reference and back-ground checks? If that's so, why would they not give you a conditional offer letter? On the other hand, as Bob Brown says…

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I wouldn't be concerned.

In German academia, it is rather common to make PhD/postdoc offers informally (i.e. just via email etc.), and the formal process is only completed at a much later point.  I know of many cases where people only sign their contract on their first working day (in particular in pre-Corona times, administration wanted to do the signing in person, so if you were in a different place, this would be postponed until you arrived).

On the other hand, even without the contract, you can get a confirmation that you *will* be hired in the future, once the necessary paperwork is completed.

However, it will be impossible to get such a confirmation *without* having the required paperwork completed - just imagine that in the course of that, it turns out that you don't have the required qualifications (no PhD, no degree, ... ) - the administration will not sign that they will hire you unless they are sure that this is legally possible.

One thing you can do to speed up at least part of the process - to make sure that you don't "accidentally" miss a qualification (very unlikely) - is to supply all required documents as soon as possible and check that they are sufficient. Even if the process is not completed yet, this should give you additional security that things will not go wrong for formal reasons (again, rather unlikely - they hire people all the time).

Finally, while on the one hand I understand that you want a more formal "safety" that you will get the job, as I said this is rather normal, so no need to worry.  But more importantly, you should note that even if you have a contract, within the first 6 months you can be usually fired on short notice and without a reason given (I'm pretty sure this is more or less the same in other places, that there is an initial period where both parties can terminate the employment on short notice, not to speak of places like the US), so even if you have a written offer or even a signed contract, there is still some amount of risk involved, like essentially always in life (unless you have a tenured position).

*Edit:* Maybe to add a comment, hiring decisions typically have to be approved by the personnel council, and possibly other bodies (equal opportunities, etc.), which can take its time, especially at large universities or research institutes. In addition, if this a position funded by public money, it has to be publicly advertised in one way or the other, and the advertisement has to be open for a certain amount of time (I think 2 weeks at least), before the whole process can even start.
So putting all these processes together,
2 months might well be the minimum time it takes.

Comment: Perhaps it is worthwhile mentioning that also the "equal opportunities officer" can, depending on the state, effectively veto a hiring process, and this person will not be informed until the hiring process is started. This is another reason for why there are no offer letters - they would either be meaningless in such an environment or promise something that the hiring university cannot actually guarantee, which is legally highly problematic.

Answer (score 6):

The concept of an offer letter is not a universal one.

Based on my own experience in Germany, as well as what I've heard from colleagues, I don't think they really exist at German universities. I once was in the process of being hired on a temporary professership at a German university, and they had me sign all kinds of ancillary paperwork and got to the point where I was listed as the instructor on the course pages I would have done without there ever being something like an offer letter.

I don't think there is anything more reasonable you can do than going along with the process, and not stop considering backup plans.

Comment: Professor hirings in Germany (i.e. Beamter) is entirely different. This is not a good comparison.

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak directly about Germany, but acquiring work visas for foreign postdocs in China can take 3-4 months. The official offer letter from the university only comes after the visa is acquired. Your new PI should be able to tell you if the process of generating an official offer letter after a faculty has requested one to be made has ever fallen through. For us, HR will evaluate the candidate immediately and let us know if there are any issues (e.g. insufficient work experience; candidate cannot supply a diploma). At our institute I'm not aware of any cases where a qualified candidate did not get an official offer.

I will add that the COVID-19 pandemic is adding a lot of uncertainty to these things. It is possible that the university suspends hiring for budgetary reasons.